# How to maintain the web application UI after browser refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, refresh, partial

I am new to Asp Net MVC, and I appreciate your help on this problem: I have a web application launched by a hosting website. The web application is a collection of partial views posted to the client side according to user interactions which trigger controller actions to post additional partial views. At a given moment, the application might have say 5 partial views displayed on the client side in a certain layout. If the browser page gets refreshed for whatever reason, my application is reset to its initial state (i.e. accessing the Index Controller Action) as if it is launched for the first time. But I want my application UI to maintain all the partial views that have been posted to the client before the refresh occurred. Do I need to have a mechanism to re post all the partial views again, this does not seem realistic. What do you think the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to keep the state either in session or in browser storage space. And get javascript to load your partials on page (re)load. And I'd prefer to do this with browser storage.

MVC does not have any kind of inbuilt functionality to do this, so it is all yours to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the info, when you stated "get javascript to load your partials on page (re)load", do you mean javascript issuing postback requests to controller and re-play the partial views. Or you mean the javascript itself does that without postback, if so, does not that need to have all kind of state info in local storage for javascript to use?

Comment: I meant for JS to replay POST/GET requests to get parts of your page. And browser state to keep what exact parts to get loaded into the page.